# Laravel 5.1 sending email error : stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1, swiftmailer

I am using Laravel 5.1 , I want to send email (smtp)
this is my `.env` config :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.ir
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=account@mydomain.ir
MAIL_PASSWORD= ....
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

and this in `config/mail.php`  :

```
'from' => ['address' =>env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'account@mydomain.ir'), 'name' => 'ESET'],
```

and a test function to send an simple test email :

```
public function getEm()
{
    $input = [] ;
    Mail::send('emails.simple', $input, function($message) {
            $message->to('some@gmail.com', 'Learning')->subject('Contact view Our Contact Form');
    });
    return 'Your message has been sent';
}
```

and when I test this  project in localhost ( in WampServer) I works good and sends email ok !

But when I want to use it in server(online) I will change my `.env` config as my host support says like this  :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=account@mydomain.ir
MAIL_PASSWORD=....
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I See this error :

> ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 275:
>
> stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
>
> in StreamBuffer.php line 275 at HandleExceptions->handleError('2',
> 'stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
> given',
> '/home2/net45987/domains/esetn32.ir/public_html/la/user/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php',
> '275', array('host' => 'localhost', 'timeout' => '30', 'options' =>
> array(), 'streamContext' => resource, 'errno' => null, 'errstr' =>
> null)) at stream_set_blocking(null, '1') in StreamBuffer.php line 275
> at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() in
> StreamBuffer.php line 62 at
> Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(array('protocol' => null,
> 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => '587', 'timeout' => '30', 'blocking'
> => '1', 'tls' => false, 'type' => '1', 'stream_context_options' => array())) in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 113 at
> Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() in Mailer.php line 79
> at Swift_Mailer->send(object(Swift_Message), array()) in Mailer.php
> line 395 at Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(object(Swift_Message)) in
> Mailer.php line 181 at Mailer->send('emails.simple', array(),
> object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 222 at
> Facade::__callStatic('send', array('emails.simple', array(),
> object(Closure))) in CallbackController.php line 114 at
> Mail::send('emails.simple', array(), object(Closure)) in
> CallbackController.php line 114 at CallbackController->getEm()

Comment: Try to check if the function "proc_open" is enabled by your hoster, e.g. with this small snippet: `<?php
echo function_exists('proc_open') ? "Yep, that will work" : "Sorry, that won't work";
?>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved this problem for so long?I've had the same problem recently.The solution is:

1. Cloud virtual machine environment does not support stream_socket_client function.
2. Just change him to fsockopen function.port is 465 ssl,because 25 be banned.Similar to the `$this->stream = @fsockopen($host, $this->params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout)`
3. open fsockopen function in Cloud virtual machine background.

My English is not very good,sorry.